# Select the changes of a textbox that was disabled from code behind in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a page with a `asp:textBox`.
In my code behind (VB.net) in the Page Load, depending on such filters, i'm going to enable/disable this `asp:textBox` in this way:

```
this.txtB.Enabled = true;
this.txtB.Enabled = false;
```

In the moment that the user change the context of this `asp:Textbox` (only if it's enabled) i want to do some stuff, and so i thought to use jQuery in this way:

```
 $('.txtB:enabled').on("propertychange input paste", function () { ... });
```

The problem is that, in some cases, the textBox that in the beginning was disabled had to become enabled too. And i do that always in jQuery:

```
$(".txt_PISocAppNom").prop('disabled', false);
```

But in this case when then the user change  the context of the textBox, the previous method didn't catch the changes.

I assume that the problem derive from the fact that in my code behind i'm setting the ENABLE attribute and in jQuery the DISABLE attribut.

I don't know if my supposition is correct and in that case how to change the code to make it work.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle with rendered HTML ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using 'live' instead of 'on'?

```
$('.txtB:enabled').live("propertychange input paste", function () { ... });
```

If your textbox is disabled at the beginning the selector '.txtB:enabled' won't apply to it so the change event will not get attached to it. Using 'live' will make sure that the event also gets attached for the future elements.

'live' has been deprecated in the new versions of jquery. In jquery 1.7+ you can also use `$('.parentB').on("propertychange input paste", ".txtB:enabled", function () { ... });` to get the same result as 'live'. I'm using '.parentB' as a selector to get the parent of your textbox.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i inserted the

```
 $(".txtB:enabled").on("propertychange input paste", function () { ... });
```

in the

```
 $(document).ready(function () { ... });
```

In that case, it was attacked in the early stages only to those items that were enabled. So, if my textbox was at first disabled, and enabled only later it hadn't the `.on(...)` property.